# Jquery Show Tabs

Tags: jquery

I like to show tabs on my page. For example the first tab
will say First and the second tab will say Second.
When the user clicks on a tab, I like to show the infomation in a div.

Comment: Cool. Can you post what you've tried so far and where you got stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

I would suggest jquery-ui's `.tabs()` since you tagged jquery.